# Questions on binary search tree mirroring

Tags: binary-search-tree

I have written 2 methods to find out If an tree is an BST. Most these samples are from stanford courses on web.

before mirroring:
Tree is BST: true (results from first method)
Tree is BST2: true (results from second method)

after mirroring:
Tree is BST: false (results from first method)
Tree is BST2: true (results from second method)

If a binary search tree is mirrored. I believe it will not be an BST anymore. Is that right?
Is the second method wrong?

```
//mirror
public void mirror(){
    mirror(root);
}

private void mirror(Node node){
    if(node == null) return;

    if( node != null){
        mirror(node.left);
        mirror(node.right);

        Node temp = node.left;
        node.left = node.right;
        node.right = temp;
    }

}

public boolean isBST(){
    return isBST(root);
}

private boolean isBST(Node node){
    if( node == null) return true;

    if( node.left != null && maxValue(node.left) > node.data) return false;
    if( node.right != null && minValue(node.right) <= node.data) return false;

    return (isBST(node.left) && isBST(node.right));
}

public boolean isBST2(){
    return isBST2(root, Integer.MIN_VALUE, Integer.MAX_VALUE);
}

private boolean isBST2(Node node, int minVal, int maxVal){
    if( node == null) return true;
    else{
        boolean leftOk = isBST2(node.left, minVal, node.data);

        if(!leftOk) return false;

        boolean rightOk = isBST2(node.right, node.data+1, maxVal);

        return rightOk;
    }
}



    //insert with inserts - tree increases on right if inserted in order
    bt = new BinaryTree();
    bt.insert(5);
    bt.insert(3);
    bt.insert(7);
    bt.insert(1);
    bt.insert(4);
    bt.insert(6);
    bt.insert(9);
    bt.printTree();
    bt.printPostorder();
    System.out.println("max depth: " + bt.maxDepth());
    System.out.println("min value: " + bt.minValue());
    System.out.println("max value: " + bt.maxValue());
    System.out.println("size of tree: " + bt.size());
    System.out.println("Has path sum 8: " + bt.hasPathSum(8));
    System.out.println("Has path sum 9: " + bt.hasPathSum(9));
    bt.printPath();
    System.out.println("Trees are same: " + bt.sameTree(bt));
    System.out.println("Trees is BST: " + bt.isBST());
    System.out.println("Trees is BST: " + bt.isBST2());
    bt.mirror();
    System.out.println("Path after mirroring BST");
    bt.printPath();
    System.out.println("Trees is BST: " + bt.isBST());
    System.out.println("Trees is BST: " + bt.isBST2());
    System.out.println("---------------------");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`isBST2()` does not correctly return if the tree is a BST or not.

In fact it always returns `true`. When `node` is `null` it will return true. Further see that in `isBST2()` there is no condition checking except `if(!leftOk)`. So if `leftOk` is `true` it does not return `false`. So the function always returns `true`. Hence this function is not correct.

Whereas, the function `isBST()` is correct.

So your guess is correct.

---

Also, when a BST is mirrored, it does not remain a BST, unless it contains only one node.

Comment: thanks for helping. I think there is no comparison happening.

Comment: Thanks for helping. I think the logic is wrong as you pointed out. 

can you also help with the following post if you have time -http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23024610/deleting-an-node-in-bst